# Getting JAX-RS service to create an object with a JsonObject property

Tags: java, json, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I'd like to get JAXRS to push all json details for a specific class property into a JsonObject object.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class MyMessage implements Serializable {

    private PayloadType payloadType;    

    private JsonObject payload;
}
```

REST method of:

```
@POST
@Path("/send")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response send(MyMessage message)
```

I'd like to POST the following JSON, but have the `payload` property set as a `javax.json.JsonObject` object.

```
{
   payloadType:'MESSAGE',
   payload:{
      subject:"My Subject",
      body:"This is a message"
   }
}
```

I'm running on Glassfish, so I was expecting that message reader for `JsonObject` were included with `org.glassfish.jersey.media`, which is support to be included in the GF4.1.  Add the following maven dependency just causes ambiguous class exceptions.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple things stopping you here.

1. `javax.json` (or JSONP) does not handle POJOs. It only handles the `javax.json` API. If you what you are expecting is that the original provider handle the POJO, while the JSONP provider handle the `javax.json`, it doesn't work like that. Either you will use the one that handles the POJOs (which doesn't know `javax.json` or you use the one that handles `javax.json`. (We do make this happen below though :-)
2. Glassfish's default provider is MOXy. So we need to disable to to use any other provider. To disable MOXy, you need to set this property

   > [`ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE)

   to `true`. Either in your web.xml or your Java config.

So to make this work, we should make sure that we are using Jackson. Jackson has the [jackson-datatype-jsr353](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr353) module which allows to do exactly what you are trying to do, `javax.json` in POJO.

Glassfish has the Jackson provider already, but you should add it anyway in a `provided` scope. So add these two dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr353</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If yoo pay attention to the versions, I am using the same versions that are included in Glassfish 4.1. It uses Jersey 2.10.4 and Jackson 2.3.3. You want the versions to conflict. Even though the `jersey-media-json-jackson` is provided, it's still a good idea to try and use the same version as the server, when compiling.

Also you should register the `JacksonFeature` with your application.

And the last thing we need is to register the `JSR353Module` so that we can get the `javax.json` support with Jackson. To do that just register the following provider with your application.

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperProvider() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JSR353Module());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

That's it. I've tested it, and it should work.

Comment: My starting conditions might be a bit different (e.g. I have the variables annotated with @JsonProperty in my otherwise POJO class) but the only thing that was missing for me was: "Also you should register the JacksonFeature with your application."
Sth like: 
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfiguration() {
        packages("your.packages");
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }   
}