# Jersey/MOXy arbitrary JSON property

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

I have a bean with an arbitrary `JsonValue` property which I need to marshal/unmarshal from JSON.

```
public class MyBean {
    public String name;
    public JsonValue data;
}
```

Since `JsonValue` is the standard `javax.json.JsonValue`, I was expecting MOXy to marshal/unmarshal it out of the box, instead I got a plain string:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "data": "{\"some\":\"json\"}"
}
```

where I was expecting this:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "data": {
    "some": "json"
  }
}
```

When unmarshalling, `data` becomes `null`. How can I use `JsonValue`s and get MOXy manage them like expected?

(I need to stick with default Jersey/MOXy, so no use of other libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this is not an answer (solution for the OP). I typed it out before I read *"I need to stick with default Jersey/MOXy"*. Was going to change to a comment, but there's too much stuff. I'll just leave it up for future readers.**

There is a [different provider](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p) for the `javax.json` classes. MOXy doesn't know how to handle them the way you expect. Without looking at any source code I would guess that what you are seeing is the value of `toString()` from the `JsonValue` instance. This is what will happen if the type can't be handled. You'll just get a `toString()` call.

Even if you add the dependency I linked to, you still have the problem that different providers don't interact with each other. What would need to happen is that in the middle of MOXy serializing the `MyBean` instance, if it sees a `javax.json` object, it tries to look for a different provider to handle it. It just doesn't work like that. Only one provider will be used.

The only solution I can think of is to instead of using MOXy, use Jackson, which has a module that supports `javax.json`. If you register that module with Jackson, it will know how to handle the `javax.json` types, "mid-serialization". You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458420/2587435), which describes the step you should take to make it work with Jackson.

Comment: I also changed to Jackson. After trying to stick with MOxy because it is the new default JSON provider for Jersey, I ran into trouble, and so more trouble until I switched and never had any more problems.